How to detect 2d datamatrix in image with Python
I have a set of medical forms that may or may not contain a 2d datamatrix into a corner of the page. I need to detect if the 2d datamatrix is present or not. For now, it's not necessary to read the content of the barcode.
I've been looking for different libraries but I can't find one with OCR or something that may detect the presence of the 2d datamatrix.
I need to do this with Python.
Attached is a medical form example where a 2d datamatrix is located at the right bottom of the page. In this case, the algorithm should say "True" as the datamatrix exists in the page.
PS: I've tested AWS Textract and is not detecting the datamatrix.


This looks relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67922660/scan-datamatrix-codes-from-pdf-file-and-save-them-to-csv

Thanks for the comment. I tested and it's not working due to a dependency error.

Id retry that after installing https://pypi.org/project/frontend/   or download the files directly from that website if there's version compatibility issues

Here are the steps to detect the 2D DataMatrix:

Install dynamsoft_capture_vision_bundle and opencv python
pip install dynamsoft-capture-vision-bundle opencv-python


Create a Python script as follows. You need to replace the test.png and LICENSE-KEY with your own. The license key can be obtained from here.
import sys
from dynamsoft_capture_vision_bundle import *
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from utils import *

image_path = 'test.png'

error_code, error_message = LicenseManager.init_license(
 "LICENSE-KEY")
if error_code != EnumErrorCode.EC_OK and error_code != 
EnumErrorCode.EC_LICENSE_CACHE_USED:
    print("License initialization failed: ErrorCode:",
       error_code, ", ErrorString:", error_message)

    sys.exit()

cvr_instance = CaptureVisionRouter()
result = cvr_instance.capture(
 'test.png', EnumPresetTemplate.PT_READ_BARCODES.value)
if result.get_error_code() != EnumErrorCode.EC_OK:
    print("Error:", result.get_error_code(),
       result.get_error_string())

    sys.exit()

cv_image = cv2.imread(image_path)

items = result.get_items()
print('Found {} barcodes.'.format(len(items)))
for item in items:
    format_type = item.get_format()
    text = item.get_text()
    print("Barcode Format:", format_type)
    print("Barcode Text:", text)

    location = item.get_location()
    x1 = location.points[0].x
    y1 = location.points[0].y
    x2 = location.points[1].x
    y2 = location.points[1].y
    x3 = location.points[2].x
    y3 = location.points[2].y
    x4 = location.points[3].x
    y4 = location.points[3].y
    del location

    cv2.drawContours(
     cv_image, [np.intp([(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), (x4, y4)])], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.putText(cv_image, text, (x1, y1 - 10),
             cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)

max_width = 1600
max_height = 1000

original_height, original_width = cv_image.shape[:2]

scaling_factor = min(
 max_width / original_width, max_height / original_height)

new_width = int(original_width * scaling_factor)
new_height = int(original_height * scaling_factor)

resized_image = cv2.resize(
 cv_image, (new_width, new_height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

cv2.imshow(
 "Original Image with Detected Barcodes", resized_image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()



Run the script:
Found 1 barcodes.
Barcode Format: 134217728
Barcode Text: Edu-barcode-45




